# Invoking headless Chrome from C# doesn't work if Chrome is already running

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to invoke the new headless chrome mode (headless=new) to create a PDF file from my C# application.  I've found it only works if Chrome is not already running.  Is there a workaround so it will always work?

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"--headless=new --print-to-pdf=c:\temp\test.pdf https://google.com";
  process.Start();
  process.WaitForExit();
```

This code works if Chrome is not running, but doesn't work if it is.  I could find no errors in any log.  Also the --remote-debugging-port=xxx did nothing in my testing trying to invoke it from C#.